# what is a "convolution warmup"?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, gpu, conv-neural-network, convolution

i encountered this phrase few times before, mostly in the context of neural networks and tensorflow, but i get the impression its something more general and not restricted to these environments.

[here](https://github.com/tensorpack/tensorpack/blob/master/examples/FasterRCNN/NOTES.md) for example, they say that this "convolution warmup" process takes about 10k iterations.

why do convolutions need to warmup? what prevents them from reaching their top speed right away?

one thing that i can think of is memory allocation. if so, i would expect that it would be solved after 1 (or at least <10) iteration. why 10k?

*edit for clarification: i understand that the warmup is a time period or number of iterations that have to be done until the convolution operator reaches its top speed (**time per operator**).
what i ask is - why is it needed and what happens during this time that makes the convolution faster?*

Answer (score 2):

Training neural networks works by offering training data, calculating the output error, and backpropagating the error back to the individual connections. For symmetry breaking, the training doesn't start with all zeros, but by random connection strengths.

It turns out that with the random initialization, the first training iterations aren't really effective. The network isn't anywhere near to the desired behavior, so the errors calculated are large. Backpropagating these large errors would lead to overshoot.

A warmup phase is intended to get the initial network away from a random network, and towards a first approximation of the desired network. Once the approximation has been achieved, the learning rate can be accelerated.

This is an empirical result. The number of iterations will depend on the complexity of your program domain, and therefore also with the complexity of the necessary network. Convolutional neural networks are fairly complex, so warmup is more important for them.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, but i'm afraid this answer doesn't address my main concern - why does it take so many iterations to reach the top speed (= time per iteration, or time per convolution).
just to be clear - i was not relating to the learning rate, which for the best of my knowledge doesnt affect the time per convolution operation (or generraly, the time per iteration).
heads up for the fast respond anyway! :)

Comment: @akonsk: You seem to be the only one that is claiming the timer per iteration varies.

Comment: i must admit that i couldnt find more examples on google right now, but i'm quite sure i've encountered this phrase in this context at least 1 more time. 
so how would you interpret the comment about the warm up (under the "Speed" section) in the link i brought?

Comment: @akonsk: I'd interpret it as the speed of learning, aka the learning rate. That's a constant which determines how much change you backpropagate given a certain error vector after forward propagation. Initially you make fairly small changes to the network as it's still so random.

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone to claiming the timer per iteration varies.
I run the same example and I get the same question.And I can say the main reason is the differnet input image shape and obeject number to detect.
I offer my test result to discuss it.
I enable trace and get the timeline at the first,then I found that Conv2D occurrences vary between steps in gpu stream all compulte,Then I  use export TF_CUDNN_USE_AUTOTUNE=0 to disable autotune.
then there are same number of Conv2D in the timeline,and the time are about 0.4s .

the time cost are still different ,but much closer!